# Brackets too large when using displaystyle and \left and \right in a fraction

Tags: displaystyle

I am trying to display a function of a fraction where I am using displaystyle in the numerator. Here is the markup:

```
\[
\text{Var}(\overline{x}) = \text{Var}\left(\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{n}\right)
\]
```

Which displays like this, with the brackets way lower than the bottom of the fraction:

[image]

When I remove \displaystyle it looks fine but I want the limits of the sum to be above and below the sigma.

Comment: fraction bars are on the math axis, and () are always vertically centred on the math axis so what you show is the expected result, you could have smaller raised () or have smaller () around a lowered fraction, which do you want ? (neither looks too good in practice)

Comment: note you can use `\limits` to get limits above and below the smaller textstyle sum, you don't need displaystyle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am after smaller brackets and a slightly lowered fraction. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Don't use `\text` for this, this is not what `\text` is made for. It is not "upright text" it follows the text font and thus you might even end up with an italic `Var`. BTW why not `\left(\frac{1}[n}\sum...\right)`, this just seems a waste of space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Four ways. I could not think to a description for the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\Var(\bar{x})&=\Var\left(\begin{matrix}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}\end{matrix}\right)
\tag{---}
\\[2ex]
\Var(\bar{x})&=\Var\left(\begin{matrix}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}\end{matrix}\right)
\tag{ugly}
\\[2ex]
\Var(\bar{x})&=\Var\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n}\right)
\tag{bad}
\\[2ex]
\Var(\bar{x})&=\Var\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\biggr)
\tag{good}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the fourth option. In my opinion (I'm an econometrician...), it's the *only* good solution. :-)

Comment: A couple of suggestions for the first one: horrific, revolting, loathsome, sickening... `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

I propose one of these solutions, using  `pmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}

\begin{document}

\[
\Var(\overline{x}) = \Var\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\displaystyle ∑_{i=1}ⁿ X_{i}}{n}\end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
\Var(\overline{x}) = \Var\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum\nolimits_{i=1}ⁿ X_{i}}{n}\end{pmatrix}
\]

 \end{document}
```

[image]